# Javascript: Converting a string of 2 characters into an Integer

Tags: javascript, arduino

To have a background, I'm using Node.js SerialPort stuff to interact with my Arduino.

I'm successful in converting my integers in Javascript ranging from [0 to 65535] into a two byte string and having them sent over to Arduino via serial.

Now, having a similar transmission from Arduino (ie. a string of two bytes) converted to an Integer in JS has become a challenge.

There should be a simple Chr() and Asc() functions for data transmission and parsing files, etc.

Arduino Code:

```
int num = 4143;
Serial3.write(highByte(num));
Serial3.write(lowByte(num));
Serial3.write('\n');
```

Javascript Code:

```
function messageReceived(msg) {
    ???   
    console.log(msg);
}
```

Comment: what does not work with [`Number#toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) or [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) with a radix?

Comment: `msg` is two bytes? so you mean something like `(msg.charCodeAt(0) << 8) + msg.charCodeAt(1)`?

Comment: in the arduino code you declared `int number` and used `num`, is it intentional? are you using some variable not showed in the example? or is a typo?

Comment: Sorry, it's supposed to be num, I fixed the code here. But in my original code I'm using some arrays so brought in here like this for simplicity